# Accessible from only one class

Tags: oop, class, internal, access-modifiers

I have a class and a method in it. The method's access modifier is now private but it can be changed. Now i just want the method to be seen only one another class.

the other class and my class are in same directory by the way.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to allow a method in a class to be available to only one other class is to use a nested private class.

```
public class Enclosing
{
   private class InnerClass
   {
      public void MyMethodThatCanOnlyBeUsedByEnclosingClass()
      {}
   }
}
```